# Error setting custom trust store for Eureka Discovery client by overriding DiscoveryClient.DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, truststore, sslcontext

I am upgrading a spring-boot project from an old version (2.2.9.RELEASE + Spring Cloud HOXTON.SR12) to v2.6.1 + Spring Cloud 2021.0.0

The issue I am currently hitting is with Trust Store enabled Eureka clients. In my old version, all eureka registering applications would use
`import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;` and be tagged with
`@EnableDiscoveryClient`

To use a custom trust store, I'd then include the following beans in a configuration class:

```
  @Bean
  public DiscoveryClient.DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs getTrustStoredEurekaClient(SSLContext sslContext) {
    DiscoveryClient.DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs args = new DiscoveryClient.DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs();
    args.setSSLContext(sslContext);
    return args;
  }
 

  @Bean
  public SSLContext sslContext() throws Exception {
    return new SSLContextBuilder().loadTrustMaterial(new File(trustStore).toURI().toURL(), trustStorePassword.toCharArray()).build();
  }
```

using `import com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient;`

Following the upgrade, any microservice which attempts to use this custom truststore will not start, with the error thrown below:

> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field optionalArgs in
> org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration
> required a bean of type
> 'com.netflix.discovery.AbstractDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs' that could
> not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'com.netflix.discovery.AbstractDiscoveryClientOptionalArgs' in your
> configuration.

It doesn't seem to matter if I try to autowrire in a separate bean of type `DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs` and set the context to this, and I am currently unable to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this by setting the following in the gateway's application.properties:

```
eureka.client.tls.enabled=true
eureka.client.tls.key-store=file:<path-to-key-store>
eureka.client.tls.key-store-password=<password>
eureka.client.tls.keyStoreType=PKCS12
eureka.client.tls.keyPassword=<password>
eureka.client.tls.trust-store=file:<path-to-trust-store>
eureka.client.tls.trust-store-password=<password>
```

What's not clear to me is why a keystore in addition to the truststore needs to be set (as above, it was only necessary to configure a trust store for the SSL context of the DiscoveryClient override for the previous versions using Zuul), which suggests I haven't fully understood what's actually happening here.

Comment: not working for me :/