# Spring cloud gateway does not forward HTTPS correctly

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, microservices, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I've recently migrated a microservices backend to Spring boot v2.6.1 + spring cloud v2021.0.0 (old version was v2.2.1.RELEASE).

Previously, the setup included a discovery server (Eureka), a gateway (Zuul) and various microservices accessible externally via the gateway. All of these were TLS/secure port enabled so all requests (discovery, registration, gateway forwarding etc) required SSL trust store configuration.

Since Zuul is no longer supported in this version, I am switching to Spring cloud gateway, with the following application.properties setup:

```
server.port = 8080

eureka.instance.securePortEnabled=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone = http://localhost:8761/eureka/

spring.application.name= gateway-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=first-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=lb://FIRST-SERVICE
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0].name=Path
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0].args.pattern=/firstService/**
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=StripPrefix=1

security.require-ssl=true
server.ssl.key-store=keystore.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12
server.ssl.keyAlias=localhost

spring.cloud.gateway.httpclient.ssl.trustedX509Certificates[0]=cert.pem
```

Without ssl universally disabled, I can access a first service URL via that gateway without issue. With SSL enabled, I can access the first service directly and again no issue:

`https://localhost:8100/test`

> { "message": "Hello World!" }

However, the gateway is not correctly forwarding the requests either via the correct protocol or with the correct client certificate. I am getting the below error response instead of "Hello World" message:

`https://localhost:8080/firstService/test`

> Bad Request This combination of host and port requires TLS.

(It's worth noting that the Eureka secure port is disabled, and registration/registry fetch is done via HTTP due to issues logged at  [Error setting custom trust store for Eureka Discovery client by overriding DiscoveryClient.DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71980681/error-setting-custom-trust-store-for-eureka-discovery-client-by-overriding-disco)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this comes down to how the microservices register with Eureka.

Although FIRST-SERVICE was also setup with `security.require-ssl=true` for direct access it was also necessary to register with Eureka with SSL enabled.

Adding the settings below to application.properties fixed the issue without any changes needed for the gateway configuration:

```
eureka.client.tls.enabled=true
eureka.client.tls.key-store=file:<path-to-key-store>
eureka.client.tls.key-store-password=<password>
eureka.client.tls.keyStoreType=PKCS12
eureka.client.tls.keyPassword=<password>
eureka.client.tls.trust-store=file:<path-to-trust-store>
eureka.client.tls.trust-store-password=<password>
```